# Синтаксис Node.js

Tags: node.js, javascript

Пмогите разобраться.  1 строчка - создается объект, а остальные создают ассоциативные массивы и в них записываются методы?

```
 var handle = {}
 handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
 handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
 handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В JavaScript нет ассоциативных массивов. Если вам нужно хранить множество пар ключ:значение, то используйте объекты. Объекты нельзя считать ассоциативными массивами, т.к. они не хранят порядка.

В приведённом коде создаётся пустой объект, и записываются значения в поля с соответствующим ключом.

Comment: По мне, так вот это:

      var handle = {}

есть ни что иное, как определение нового пространства имен.

Comment: @Asen - ага, точно...

    $array = array();

Это тоже пространство имен :D

Comment: Ну а что тогда по-вашему:

     var handle = {}

Comment: Создание экземпляра класса Object как-бы, не?

Ох LOL, читаем внимательно - Подготовка **объекта**(именно объекта) поддержки пространства имен.

Для особо соображающих - в JS нет пространств имен и объекты используются для их симуляции.

PS: еще и спорит, ОМГ

Comment: Ну я как бэ это не от болды взял:

http://webscript.ru/stories/07/05/10/5470561

----
Собственно, **var handle={}** == **var handle=new Object()**

Comment: > использоваться для эмуляции пространства имен

Это не пространства имён. Просто так можно структурировать код в JavaScript, и всё.

Comment: Да? А в недавно прочитанной мною книге четко говорится, что так можно определить новое пространство имен. Даже полез смотреть =)

Comment: Так можно эмулировать пространство имен, на самом деле это примерно такое-же пространство имен как и статический класс.

Если там написано именно **определить новое пространство имен**, т.е. слово в слово, то в ведро книгу т.к. это абсурд.

`var handle={} == var handle=new Object()` что вы хотели этим сказать?..

PS: не стоит доказывать того, в чем вы сами не уверены либо не разбираетесь. Лучше писать как-то так - я думаю, я полагаю и т.д.

PPS: ни книга, ни предоставленная вами ссылка не является авторитетным источником. К тому-же, по ссылке, все правильно пишут, вы просто были невнимательны

Comment: По-моему разными словами об одном и том же. `var handle = {}` - действительно, это можно трактовать, как создание нового пространства имён. Хотя конечно, тут создаётся объект.

Comment: @Kremchik, пространства имён могут быть вложенные, можно обращаться к членам описанным выше по дереву как к своим. С объектами в js это не так.

Comment: @Kremchik, ога, с таким же успехом пространством имен можно считать и функцию и массив, а так-же, строку, число, булиан, которые были инициализированы с помощью new, собственно пара примеров:
    
var lol = new Boolean();
    lol.test = function() {
     console.log( this.testResult );
    }
    lol.testResult = 'ololo';
    lol.test(); // -> ololo

    var func = function(){}
    func.test = function() {
     console.log( this.testResult )
    }
    func.testResult = 'ololo';
     func.test(); // -> ololo
    // etc...

Именно поэтому - нет, так трактовать, мягко говоря, не совсем верно

Comment: По поводу ответа. А разве ассоциативные массивы должны хранить порядок? Мне всегда казалось что а.м. это такое альтернативное название для словарей/хэшмапов (педивикия соглашается, но можно ли ей верить — не знаю).

А если порядок держать не нужно, то объекты в JS это, по сути, выходит, и есть словари с сахарком. Если я ничего из виду не упускаю.

Comment: 1. Объекты хранят порядок. С небольшим уточнение про числовые ключи. 2. Есть Map. 3. Кто сказал, что ассоциативный массив должен хранить порядок?